# Optimizing an inner join that is orders of magnitude slower than a direct SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In summary, I am trying to implement an inner join in pyspark. Running the join directly as a SQL query against the database takes about 45 seconds. I've been running it in pyspark for over 14 hours now, without terminating, and it looks like it will take at least 5 days to converge. I really need to speed up this query.

In detail, I have two tables, `PARENT` and `CHILD`. The `PARENT` table has columns `parent_id`, `timestamp`, and some metadata. The `CHILD` table has columns `child_id`, `parent_id`, `value` and some metadata. I want to do a simple inner join on `parent_id` for the last three hours of data.

The challenge here is the scale. In total, `PARENT` has around 300 million rows and `CHILD` has nearly a billion. However, when `PARENT` is filtered to the last three hours, we receive on the order of 100k rows. The SQL query that terminates in 45 seconds is as follows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PARENT
INNER JOIN CHILD ON PARENT.parent_id = CHILD.parent_id
WHERE PARENT.timestamp >= SYSDATE - 3/24;
```

The commensurate pyspark code (which I would hope would execute in a similar time to the raw SQL, but instead is expected to take more than 5 days) is as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timestamp
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# load PARENT into `parent` and CHILD into `child`
# ...

parent = parent.where(F.col("timestamp") >= datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3))
joined = parent.join(child, "parent_id")
```

Upon investigation of the SQL / DataFrame DAG on the spark ui, I noticed that the reason for the slowness is that spark is attempting to scan all billion rows in `CHILD`. Thus, I also attempted to pre-filter `child` to only include the set of `parent_id` found with the timestamp filter. The modified code is as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timestamp
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# load PARENT into `parent` and CHILD into `child`
# ...

parent = parent.where(F.col("timestamp") >= datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3))

parent_id_rows = parent.select("parent_id").collect()
parent_ids = [row.parent_id for row in parent_id_rows]

child = child.where(F.col("parent_id").isin(parent_ids))
joined = parent.join(child, "parent_id")
```

Unfortunately, this modified script runs into the same problem in the original in that spark is attempting to scan the full billion rows of `CHILD`. I've attached the DAG execution plan, after 14 hours of execution, for this modified script.

How can I speed up this query? How can I prevent a full scan of `CHILD`?

[image: The execution plan for the modified pyspark script after 14 hours of execution.]

Runtime Information:

- Java Version: 21.0.2 (Private Build)
- Scala Version: version 2.12.18

Spark Properties:

- spark.default.parallelism: 256
- spark.driver.extraJavaOptions: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
- spark.driver.memory: 64g
- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: true
- spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled: true
- spark.executor.cores: 32
- spark.executor.extraJavaOptions: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
- spark.executor.id: driver
- spark.executor.memory: 64g
- spark.master: local[*]
- spark.rdd.compress: true
- spark.scheduler.mode: FIFO
- spark.serializer.objectStreamReset: 100
- spark.sql.adaptive.enabled: true
- spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled: true
- spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: 1g  # I've played around with this and have similar behavior at the default 0.
- spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 64
- spark.submit.deployMode: client
- spark.task.cpus: 32

Hadoop Properties (should all be default; hadoop is not installed on my system)

System Properties:

- SPARK_SUBMIT: true
- file.encoding: utf-8
- file.separator: /
- java.class.version: 65.0
- java.runtime.name: OpenJDK Runtime Environment
- java.runtime.version: 21.0.2+13-Ubuntu-122.04.1
- os.arch: amd64
- os.name: Linux
- os.version: 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: Can you share the Cluster configuration that you have tried using as well?

Comment: How do you know that "... this modified script runs into the same problem in the original in that spark is attempting to scan the full billion rows of CHILD."?

Comment: @Lingesh.K - added to the post above. Let me know if I missed anything (I sanitized it a bit)

Comment: @Ivannpy this comes from the Scan block for `CHILD` in the DAG figure above. There are approximately 3 child rows for every parent row, and so with 76k parent rows (as seen in the scan and child blocks of the `PARENT` side of the join), we really should only have around 230k child rows. However, the scan of `CHILD` is continually incrementing, reaching 78 million rows at the time of the screenshot above (14 hours after the start), and presently at 124 million rows (21 hours after the start).

Comment: Maybe the database has built an index on those columns which is the reason why join is faster. Pyspark can't use index of the database so it might be reading the full table.

Comment: @user238607 there is an index on `CHILD`, but it is over the `child_id` column only and not the `parent_id`, so I don't see it speeding up the join. Either way, though, I really need this to run faster in pyspark if at all possible

Comment: Are you reading the parent and child tables from the database connection? If yes, that could be problematic. Dump your data into parquet files and then read data from there. It should be faster that way. You can try this strategy on smaller data first and then scale if it works.

Comment: @user238607 yes, it is a direct database connection